# how much time it will take to make a film alone

Tags: animation

I want to make short animation films like 10 to 15 min and I want it to be as good as *Frozen* and the *Lorax*. how much time, from your experience, do you think it will approximately take to make some animation as good as that to make a single film? I searched the internet for this question and it told me that it will take **months** if you are a team. and I am alone so is that really right? cus am fed up:)

Comment: If you are fed up then don't do it.  Each frame for any of the films you mention takes many minutes, sometimes hours to render in very high powered computers, and render farms comprised of thousands of computers. Multiply the time it takes to make one frame by the number of frame per second you need, then by the number of minutes of the whole film... then you will realize how unlikely it is you can do anything like that at home. Now you can really be fed up.

Answer (score 2):

Real numbers here. On Youtube you can find channel named [Astartes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFMtdiQILuTZr22sKUeAOOA). It's one guy who made 5 short (1 min - 7 min) extremely high quality movies within time span of 2 years. (Single story in five parts) At the begging he was doing this as a hobby but when [Patreons](https://www.patreon.com/astartesfilm) gave him enough support he went full time. The time between part [four](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2B6de1Geks) and [five](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoCcpMW8fSs) was around 10 months. Part 5 was 7 minutes long.

Comment: oh my god, that's a lot